# Can I get \citeauthor and \citeyear with bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I am using currently using `bibtex` and the `\cite{...}` command for all citations. Using the `cell` bibliography style, citations will appear as e.g. [Jovanović and Janičić, 2005].

However, I would like to be able to extract only the author part or the year part -- like natbib's `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear`. The reasons I don't want to use natbib are: 1) natbib changes the overall citation style to not include the brackets [] around the citation; 2) natbib doesn't support UTF-8 in the bibliography file; and 3) `\citeyear` still doesn't output a letter if the same authors published multiple papers in the same year.

Comment: Try [biblatex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) together with [biber](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biber). Together, they support `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear` out of the box. UTF-8 is the main encoding used by biblatex/biber.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second observation, that "natbib doesn't support UTF-8 in the bibliography file", isn't quite accurate: it is `bibtex`, not `natbib`, that suffers from the ASCII-128 limitation. If you can run `bibtex8` instead of `bibtex`, you can use many more Latin alphabet based character encodings.

Regarding your points 1 and 3: I'm not sure what the concerns you raise are founded on. (You did issue the command `\bibliographystyle{cell}`, right?) To get `natbib` to place square brackets rather than round parentheses around the `author,year` pair, just load the package with the `square` option and use the `\citep` command (for "parenthetical citations").

The output of the MWE below shows that `\citeyear` and `\citeauthor` work as one would expect them to. In particular, `natbib` knows perfectly well how to append `a`, `b`, etc automatically to the year if the need to do so arises.

[image]

Here's the "cellcite.tex" driver file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{cell}
\begin{document}
\citep{abcd:2006a,abcd:2006b}

\citeauthor{abcd:2006a}

\citeyear{abcd:2006b}

\bibliography{cellcite}
\end{document}
```

Finally, the MWE's bib file ("cellcite.bib"):

```
@incollection{abcd:2006a,
  author      = "Torben G. Andersen and Tim Bollerslev and 
                Peter F. Christoffersen and Francis X. 
                Diebold",
  title       = "Volatility and correlation forecasting",
  chapter     = 15,
  pages       = "777--878",
  editor      = "Graham Elliott and Clive W. J. Granger and 
                Allan Timmermann",
  booktitle   = "Handbook of Economic Forecasting, 
                Volume~1",
  publisher   = "Elsevier",
  address     = "Amsterdam",
  year        = 2006,
}

@incollection{abcd:2006b,
  author      = "Torben G. Andersen and Tim Bollerslev and 
                Peter F. Christoffersen and Francis X. 
                Diebold",
  title       = "Practical volatility and correlation 
                modeling for financial market risk 
                management (with discussion)",
  chapter     = 11,
  pages       = "513--548",
  editor      = "Mark S. Carey and Ren{\'e} M. Stulz",
  booktitle   = "The Risks of Financial Institutions",
  publisher   = "University of Chicago Press",
  address     = "Chicago and London",
  year        = 2006,
}
```

Comment: I tried changing `bibtex` to `bibtex8` and it will complain about č only if I use natbib (without, it is fine). This is why I concluded that it is natbib rather than bibtex which doesn't handle UTF-8.

Comment: Does it make any difference if in my Bib file it shows like: `@inproceedings{perrone_cvpr2014,
 author = {Daniele Perrone and Paolo Favaro},
 title = {Total Variation Blind Deconvolution: The Devil is in the Details},
 booktitle = {EEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR)},
 year = {2014}
}`? Could that be an issue?

Comment: @Royi - I'm afraid I don't understand your question. The main issue in the original query was related to accented characters; however, I don't see any such characters in your comment. What are you trying to achieve, and what's the main concern? Which bibliography style do you employ? Note that `@incollection` and `@inproceedings` are synonyms in most bibliography styles.

Comment: In the above it is: `author = "Author Name"`. In my file it is: `author = {Author Name}`. Is that a problem? Because I get the error `Author undefined for citation`. Thank You.

Comment: @Royi - I still don't understand your concern. For sure, `"..."` and `{...}` are equally valid as delimiters of a field. However, whatever the concern is, it doesn't seem to be related to the issue(s) raised in the original posting. Please post a *new query*, in which you explain the new issue(s) in sufficient detail.