# \citeauthor without natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I need to use a style file that does not allow use of `natbib`, but I still want to use something similar to the `\citeauthor` or `\citet` command from `natbib`. This similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76283/can-i-get-citeauthor-and-citeyear-with-bibtex), but that answer references use of natbib. I've also tried using `biblatex`, but the results were not close enough to the `abbrv` style that I need to use for BibTeX. Does anyone know a way around this?

Edit: the bibliography style isn't the issue. The stylefile doesn't allow using `natbib`.

Edit: Another restriction is I have to eventually make a self contained file. The recommendation is copy the `.bbl` in to where the bibliography section was, but I was unable to get a procedure like that to work with `biblatex`.

Comment: If you tried `biblatex`, have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58152/how-to-emulate-the-traditional-bibtex-styles-plain-abbrv-unsrt-alpha-as-clo

Comment: You mention you're currently using the bibliography style `abbrv`. Have you considered using the style `abbrvnat` -- which would be compatible with `natbib`?

Comment: If the class you're using doesn't allow for `natbib`, probably the people you want to submit your paper to don't want an author-year citation scheme. Emulating what `natbib` does would mean rewrite it.

Comment: @egreg One might want to have something like: Goldberg [10] showed etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the style you need to use disallows using `natbib`, the conclusion is that the organization you'll submit your paper to doesn't accept an author-year citation scheme. Most likely also `biblatex` would be rejected.

Emulating the working of `natbib` would mean rewriting it from scratch.

Comment: One might want to have something like: Goldberg [10] showed etc.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I understand, but this would require very extensive work under the risk of rejection.